# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Issue in controlling the splash screen in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to perform some validation in background and then navigate to specified dashboard, during the time the splash screen is shown to the user.

The problem is that after some time the splash screen hides automatically.

**Tried Approaches:**

1. Set the preference in config.xml:

   - `<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"  value="false"/>` or
   - `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen"  value="false"/>`
2. Rather than hiding on "ondeviceready" event , tried to hide in my JavaScript code at certain condition:

> function getResponse(response) {
>
> ```
> if (response) {  
>
> }
>
> else {
>     $.mobile.changePage("#pageID", { transition: "none", changeHash: false });
>     navigator.splashscreen.hide();
> }
> ```
>
> }

My problem is that the splash screen gets hidden automatically, even  though `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` is not called on the `deviceready` event.

Comment: And the Worklight version, is...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worklight does not currently support an ability to extend the duration of the splash screen due to the way the splash is currently being handled by the platform.